# Is it possible to use Lightroom to upload images to a server?

Tags: html, lightroom

So what I want to know is whether it is possible to upload images from lightroom via FTP to a server? Each client will get it's own folder and a login and password to view the images. I was hoping lightroom had a nice program that laid out the images nicely and allows password protection and also allows the option to give the image a title.

Is this possible to do? If so, can anyone point me in the direction of some resources showing how to do so? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the latest Lightroom 4 SDK at:  http://www.adobe.com/devnet/photoshoplightroom.html, which still contains the FTP plugin that  @mattcawley referred to.

Answer (score 1):

Adobe used to provide an FTP plugin via their downloadable Lightroom SDK but I'm not sure if this is still the case. However, there are third-party plugins that will do the job equally well.

For example: http://www.presetsheaven.com/2009/10/27/export-to-ftp-with-lightroom/

Comment: Thank you! I'll look into it. I see something about web galleries as well.

Comment: Yes, Lightroom can create web galleries directly. It's not something I need to use, but I've played with it and it's pretty good.

Comment: Does it give the ability to be password protected?

Comment: It doesn't, no. You would have to do that on the site itself.

Answer (score 0):

check out the built-in web galleries - they are easy to use and if they are not enough you can install additional even better ones - you might be interested for example in http://fonto.pl/fontogallery.html - it has the basic feaures you may need